# Padding Not Working Font Awesome Logos

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, padding

So I'm kinda new to HTML and CSS, So probably there is a really obvious answer for my question. My problem is that the right padding of my Social Media icons are not working. They're inside a div and is **floated to the left** (default by Bootstrap).

```css
.fa {
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%
}

.fa:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.content2 {
  text-align: center;
}


/* Facebook */

.fa-facebook {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
}


/* Twitter */

.fa-twitter {
  background: #55ACEE;
  color: white;
}


/*Google*/

.fa-google {
  background: #dd4b39;
  color: white;
}


/*Instagram*/

.fa-instagram {
  background: #125688;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h2>Or Alternatively, You can Contact Us Via Our Social Media Shown Below.</h2>
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-google"></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Additional Information:

Using Bootstrap 3.3.7 and Font Awesome 4.7.0 CSS

[It's Supposed to be a Circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaQKz.png)

Comment: Btw if anyone needs the complete code i'll link 'em

Comment: How do you know it's the right padding ?

Comment: width 50px = 20px padding-left + icon space  ---> no more place for padding-right (because bootstrap is adding `box-sizing:border-box`)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bother with padding - your `.fa` class can be better achieved with `line-height`

```
.fa {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to bring your icon to the middle.

```
.fa {
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 100%;
    line-height: 48px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```css
.fa {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.fa:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.content2 {
  text-align: center;
}


/* Facebook */

.fa-facebook {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
}


/* Twitter */

.fa-twitter {
  background: #55ACEE;
  color: white;
}


/*Google*/

.fa-google {
  background: #dd4b39;
  color: white;
}


/*Instagram*/

.fa-instagram {
  background: #125688;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap-grid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h2>Or Alternatively, You can Contact Us Via Our Social Media Shown Below.</h2>
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-google"></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: The circle around the "f" of Facebook looks a bit... squished. Is this meant to be happening?